# Create hostname for a computer on the network

Tags: networking, dns

I would like a hostname like mycomp.net and be assigned through DNS of the router to go to an **internal** ip address.

The end result should be people within the network can use that hostname to connect to the internal server, and outsiders cannont

Answer (score 0):

For the computer that is running it, simply use the `host` file. Could do the same for others if there is only a handful...

For the other computers re the router, it will depend on the router you have or the firewall depeding on setup. Can you please advise...

Ps. I do this with pfsesnse but not sure if you can/do run this....

Note: host file sits: 
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

usually....

Comment: I know about the host file and unfortunatly, it wont work in this situation. The computer that gets the hostname is just a webserver but cannot be accessed via outside. (company data)

Comment: fair enough, what are you running on the router? I presume it is something like WAN -> router -> firewall(?) -> Multiple VLANS? I guess it comes down to what software you have atm...

Comment: When I say company data, it isn't a very advanced buisness on the technical side. We have simply a cisco router (probably like the m10) Just a router you would probably find in a house

Comment: Just checked the router, it has dd-wrt instaled

Comment: Well if it has dd-wrt installed, you can do it via that. Any question come back and can try help you out

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a router with DD-WRT installed, you can use the DHCP Server options in the Services tab to set hostnames based on MAC addresses. Combined with the "LAN Domain" option, this allows you to access machines via my_computer.my_domain.local

If you're not using a router with DD-WRT installed, you should try it out.