# Create hostnames on LAN with DD-WRT (on Asus RT-N 16)

Tags: lan, hostname, dd-wrt

I already took a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548867/create-hostname-for-a-computer-on-the-network). But it didn't help me out.

My aim is to address targets in my home LAN via `http://myrouter` or `ftp://data` etc.
and not like `http://my_computer.my_domain.local` as someone pointed out in the question I linked.

I could solve this with editing the hosts file(s), but I want it to work from every client in my network. And since there is more than one, I don't find that a good approach.

**EDIT**

I followed the tutorial on howtogeek, and it works. But only if I manually edit the field *DNS-suffix for this connection* (freely translated from German) on my Win7 machine. If I don't do it, `ping win7` doesn't work on my Win7 computer (but it works from other computers, mobiles on the network).

I have to explicitly add the dns-suffix to make it work like: `ping win7.home.lan`
However after editing the named field, my computer suddenly 'knows himself'. Is there a better way? Or is it normal to edit the field manually, since you are there anyway, because of setting up a static ip?

Comment: I found a guide on the internet. I'll follow it and see how far I'll come http://www.howtogeek.com/69696/how-to-access-your-machines-using-dns-names-with-dd-wrt/

Comment: I thought the static IP assigned to a host name would be enough for resolution. My Linux server is getting a static IP from DD-WRT, I've given it the name `uvm1`, but I can't resolve that name from my Windows PC; is that basically the same issue you had?

Comment: The howtogeek guide totally worked for me, loving it! thx